# Trying to populate a tracking number in AMPscript code

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a button in Marketing Cloud called 'Track Your Trade' and that button looks at the `Return_Tracking__c` field in Salesforce.  I have it redirecting to a FedEx link so the customer can track their trade in FedEx.  I have the link:

https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber=[tracking_number]

...but, the tracking number is not displaying.

Can anyone help with the direct of displaying the tracking number? I the link to grab the `Returning_Tracking__c` number it populate it on the link.

For a Tracking number of `448141655777`

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(Concat('https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber=[tracking_number]/',@returnTracking))=%%">tracking</a>
```

Comment: What's the context of the send?  Do you have to retrieve the tracking number from SF or is it in the row from your sending data extension?

Comment: What is `@returnTracking` and where is it set?

Comment: We retrieve the tracking number in SF.  Return Tracking is not in the data extension.  @returnTracking is set in the AMPscript code under asset.

Comment: set @returnTracking = field(row(@tradeRows,1),"ReturnTracking__c")

Comment: Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I'd approach it like this:

```
%%[

var @trackLink
set @trackLink = ""
set @trackLink = concat(@trackLink, "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/")
set @trackLink = concat(@trackLink, "?action=track")
set @trackLink = concat(@trackLink, "&trackingnumber=", @returnTracking)

]%%
<a href="%%=redirectto(@trackLink)=%%">tracking link</a>
```

or inline:

```
<a href="%%=redirectto(concat('https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber=', @returnTracking))=%%">tracking link</a>
```

I tend to *not* do huge concats inline, just because they're harder to interpret and maintain.